# Magento admin login not working

Tags: magento, admin

I migrated my website from one hosting provider to another. Everything worked well when i changed the A-records on server before changing the Nameservers.

After the Nameserver change, problems have started creeping in. First there were no links were working. After asking the provider, they said the .htaccess was blank and they have restored the default configuration and things will work fine.

The links have started working but I am unable to login into the admin section. After clicking on the login, I am redirected to the same page without any change in the URL.

**UPDATE**

Visit http://eyaas.com/admin , enter any credentials, and click login to see the problem. Nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, delete all you cookies in your brwoser, and try again.

If the authentication succeeds (you're sure of your credentials) but magento redirects you on the admin login page without any error, the problem could be a bad synchronisation of the time between you and the server.. (the cookie created in the browser auto-destructs itself because it expires right away)

Check the server & client system date/time.

ps: did you modify all the urls in the table core_config_data ?

Comment: I just migrated the site and didn't do anything else. The migration was done from one cpanel(US) to other cpanel(India). First, I made a complete backup and then restored it here

Comment: Do you have an error after login ? If no : install "webdeveloper" addon for firefox and check your session cookies. Search for a "backend" cookie and check its validity date.

Comment: ohh k will do that now. In the meantime, do i need to empty var and cache folders via FTP ??

Comment: It can help yes (only if your cache is stored on filesystem though)

Comment: deleting or emptying magento var and cache folders won't hinder with the magento site, right ??

Comment: I tried deleting the cache and session folders, but it didn't helped. In the view cookie information, I saw that the cookie was created with the name **adminhtml** and was set to expire at end of session. You can visit this [PAGE](http://www.eyaas.com/admin). Enter any credentials and see it redirects to the same page.

Comment: The dates are OK, your cookie seems OK.. sorry no clue anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the cookie storage path so inject below update query in you Database.

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'new_domain' where `path` = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain';

in above query if your domain is www.vibrantwebstore.com than new_domain is '.vibrantwebstore.com' or leave blank('')

Answer (score 0):

try a number of different browsers including Safari or Opera. 
Chrome will give some problems and you need to remember to clear you cache in Chrome after making changes!

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install#dokuwiki__top

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me, I tried everything. Changed Varien.php file, cleared cache files and everything , still it didn't work. The issue in my case was PHP version. I had PHP 7 and my magento was 1.8 due to which it was not working, so all I did was brought my PHP to version 5.6 and it worked perfectly.