# Magento admin login not working on beta site running in subfolder

Tags: php, magento, authentication, admin

I have just migrated my Magento site on new server. Here I have 2 sites -

1. Production (running from root)
2. Beta (in beta sub folder)

Both sites are working after migration but I am not able to do admin login into beta site (Note : production site is working, am able to login in admin also)-

www.mydomain.com/beta/index.php/admin

after entring correct admin credentials still it keeps me on login page with a key in url (given below) -

```
http://mydomain.com/beta/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/7c2b1acbd7a05e8172bc685a50fe9ec7/
```

I have gone through below links -

[Magento admin login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931967/magento-admin-login-not-working?rq=1)

[Can't log in to Magento Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin)

[Magento can't login in admin with right username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860936/magento-cant-login-in-admin-with-right-username-and-password?rq=1)

[Can't login to Magento admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075539/cant-login-to-magento-admin)

But not getting exact solution. anyone please guess how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your `base_url`s look like (you can find them in the table `core_config_data`)?

Comment: That I have already changed.That is why, frontend is working properly. Only issue is with admin login

Comment: It sounds like your server time or local system time may be off.  Make sure your time is set correctly so your login doesn't automatically expire.

Comment: @seanbreeden: Can you please elaborate more about this ? How to check and fix that.

Comment: Check your local computer's time and date.  Make sure it isn't set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the rewrite base in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes. It's set to "RewriteBase /beta/" beta site is here - `http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/sitename/beta/` . Let me know if I have to do any change here. I don't think so, because forntend is working without any issue.