# Magento can't log in in admin after migration

Tags: php, magento, admin, magento-1.8

After migration I can't log in to the admin panel. After i enter the username and password, the same page reloads.
I have tried:

[Can't log in to Magento Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176195/cant-log-in-to-magento-admin)

[Magento: Can't log into admin [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817560/magento-cant-log-into-admin)

[Magento admin login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931967/magento-admin-login-not-working)

[Magento can't login in admin with right username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860936/magento-cant-login-in-admin-with-right-username-and-password)

But nothing works
I have tried to comment out the code lines in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php.
```

and nothing!

And I changed the `core_config_data` `web/unsecure/base_ur`l and `web/secure/base_url`.

I am running out of ideas,
Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:**

I checked the cookies on the old server, and when on the login page i get an `adminhtml` cookie, but not on the new i get an `hz_amChecked` cookie.

**EDIT 2:**

The new server is on siteground, maybe something I am missing on the settings there
I tried to put a `die()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the new server meets magento minimum system requirement and all folder have the correct permission? Did you clear your var/cache?

Comment: I cleared my var/cache and installed a clean version of magento and it worked, then i changed the database of the new magento installation with the old database and the same problem poped out, so the problem is somewhere in the database, i supose

Comment: Did you make any changes to `<crypt>` in /app/etc/local.xml

Comment: Haven't made any changes to the `<crypt>` in app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, it was in the `/app/etc/local.xml` in:

```
<install>
   <date><![CDATA[Day, dd Mth yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000]]></date>
</install>
```

I didn't think that the time of the installation was important, but i changed the +0000 to the same value as the new magento installation had and

```
<session_save><![CDATA[file]]></session_save>
```

to

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

cleared the files `var/cache`, `var/session` and removed all cookies from my site in the browser and it worked! Finally i can rest a little :)
Thank you all anyway for the help!

Comment: Where did you get the magento installation time value from?

Comment: @richelliot i installed magento on the server that i had to migrate my local installation and saw that the time difference was different

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue- These steps fixed my problem

**1) Clear or delete /var/cache/* and /var/session/* folder all files

2) Clear your browser cache/cookies**

If that doesn't work make sure session and cache directories are writable

optional if still not work then try this query 
In PHPMyADMIN run this query:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Answer (score 1):

What I did in this matter is I created a new Admin account I thought that I forgot the password of the admin panel.

To create a new admin user, just copy and paste the command with your values in it.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="username" --admin-password="password" --admin-email="admin@email.com" --admin-firstname="admin_first_name" --admin-lastname="Admin_last_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing `core_cofig_data` `value` field for `path` `web/secure/base_url` from non secure URL to secure URL like please change it from http://example.com/ to https://example.com/ .  It had solved my admin login problem when i migrated one of my magento website.

Answer (score 0):

Reason of the problem

Do you know why this problem occurs? The problem occurs because magneto
could not store cookies. We run it as localhost and localhost is not true
domain but to store cookies we need a domain. That’s why login stops
without saying any word.

Solution: Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
file within your magento directory.

Find the code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
  $this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
  $this->getCookie()->getPath(),
  $this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
  $this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
  $this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

and replace with

```
session_set_cookie_params(
  $this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
  $this->getCookie()->getPath()
  //$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
  //$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
  //$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *php.ini* enable `max_input_vars` and increase the value for your server

```
;How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
;max_input_vars = 1000
max_input_vars = 35000
```